# Image concatenation script

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

everyone. I'm trying to write a script that would render images from file inputs on a canvas in a row.

First I cycle through images to calculate the canvas width (because the canvas is wiped on resizing). Then cycle again to render the images.

```
canvas.width = 0;
let x = 0,
    y = 0,
    totalWidth = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".has-file").length; i++) {
  let input = document.querySelectorAll(".has-file")[i];
  let image = input.files[0];
  let img = new Image();
  console.log(img);
  img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(image);
  img.addEventListener('load', () => {
    console.log(img);
    let newWidth = img.width * canvas.height / img.height;
    totalWidth += newWidth;
    canvas.width = totalWidth;
  }, false);
};
for (let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".has-file").length; i++) {
  let input = document.querySelectorAll(".has-file")[i];
  let image = input.files[0];
  let img = new Image();
  img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(image);
  img.addEventListener('load', () => {
    let newWidth = img.width * canvas.height / img.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, newWidth, canvas.height);
    x += newWidth;
  }, false);
};
```

}

The app behaves weird, the images are not always rendered, and when they do, not always where they supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

First problem with the code is that you're loading images twice, and the randomness is due to the fact that image loading can be ambiguous. Check out this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gLfvsjza/). I have used text input instead of files, drawing takes place when it is the last image otherwise resizing the canvas can cause canvas to reset, losing the previous draw.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d', {
  antialias: false,
  depth: false
 });
canvas.width = 0;
let x = 0,
    y = 0,
    totalWidth = 0;
    let obj = [];
    let k = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".has-file").length; i++) {
  let input = document.querySelectorAll(".has-file")[i];
  let image = input.value;
  let img = new Image();
  img.src = image;//window.URL.createObjectURL(image);
  img.addEventListener('load', () => {
    console.log(img);
    let newWidth = img.width * canvas.height / img.height;
    totalWidth += newWidth;
    canvas.width = totalWidth;
    obj.push({img: img, x: x, y: y, newWidth: newWidth, height: canvas.height});
    k++;
    x += newWidth;
    if (k == document.querySelectorAll(".has-file").length )
     draw();
  }, false);
};

function draw() {
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      ctx.drawImage(obj[i].img, obj[i].x, obj[i].y, obj[i].newWidth, obj[i].height);
  }
}
```

```html
<input style="display: none;" class="has-file" value="https://i.imgur.com/I86rTVl.jpg" />
<input style="display: none;" class="has-file" value="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1446292267125-fecb4ecbf1a5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" />

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you shrys, it kinda works, but the images are not in the same order as the inputs.